# When to use repeated goodness of fit tests (G-tests) over chi-square goodness-of-fit tests

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, frequency

I am working with a large dataset that included subject's ages (continuous), sex (binary; Female or Male), service purchased (discrete & categorical, 7 levels), and year of purchase (set to be discrete).

What I am trying to do is compare frequencies of demographic data and ornamentation details. Since I will be doing multiple comparisons, I think I would also need to use adjusted p-values for multiple comparisons. Based on my reading it would appear the repeated goodness of fit test (G test) would be best suited over the chi-squared test, but I don't understand why that might be.

So, my question is: how do I know which goodness of fit test is most appropriate?

My ultimate goal is to test, for example, if there is a significant difference in the number of females vs. males that get a tattoo in 2007, and if possible, to compare this difference to another year.

Comment: Please give some quotes in context so we can understand what you're looking at; I don't see anything in what you said that would establish your conclusion.

Comment: Hi Glen, Could you explain what you mean so that I can elaborate in a more helpful manner?

Comment: "Based on my reading it would appear the repeated goodness of fit test (G test) would be best suited over the chi-squared test" .... what did you  read, exactly? What did it say? Why would it make you think that?

Comment: So, I was reading about a similar dataset in Wohlrab et al. 2007 (http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/per.642/abstract) and they used the G-test instead. In that journal article (the one cited above) it said (on page 936): "Replicated Goodness of Fit Tests (G-statistics) were conducted following Sokal and Rohlf (1981) to compare frequencies of demographic data and ornamentation details with adjusted p values for multiple comparisons." I don't see why that is a better choice over the chi-squared test.

Comment: A couple points that may or may not help: 1) For tables of nominal data, there are goodness-of-fit tests and there are tests of association.  Either one of these can be performed with chi-square or with G.  2)  One advantage of the G-test g-o-f over the chi-square g-o-f test is that the G values themselves add up, so you can decide whether replicated tests can be pooled.  I don't know if this is what the author had in mind.  Replicated G-test g-of-f is included in [The Handbook of Biological Statistics](http://www.biostathandbook.com/repgtestgof.html) (Caveat: written by a non-statistician).

Comment: @Sal Mangiafico, I suppose my problem is that I don't understand the tests well enough. I did stumble upon the handbook you cited, but my knowledge of the appropriateness of either test is too limited. Any suggestions on how to use this forum in a manner that will help me get the knowledge I'm seeking?

Comment: I would probably ask a new question, not specifically about goodness of fit tests.  Include a small, reproducible example of your data.  State specifically what you are trying to figure out.  (For example, in your question, I don't understand what variables the ornamentation would be.)  It _is_ a good idea to look at similar studies.  But it may be more important to decide what you really want to know.  For your data, it sounds like you might be able to find out what you want with simple tests of association.  For example, Sex and Service Purchased; and Age and Service Purchased.  (Continued)

Comment: (cont) You could combine data across all years, or look at years separately.  Ultimately, only you know what you want to determine...  I always recommend plotting out the data in all ways that make sense (e.g. purchases vs. year,  box plots of purchases vs. sex) and use summary statistics (e.g. contingency table of number of purchases vs. sex)...  It is helpful to learn about simple statistical tests. For beginners, I like the [Handbook of Biological Statistics](http://www.biostathandbook.com/) and I like a similar guide I wrote with a different focus [SAEPER](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/)

Comment: @Sal Mangiafico, Thank you. I will do all of the above.